# Need information regarding Ubuntu for Android

Tags: tablet, smartphone, ubuntu-for-android, arm

As far as I understand, Ubuntu for Android is not the same as Actual Ubuntu in Desktops. So I am confusing both with each other. Please enlighten me on this. Could Ubuntu on Android run 32bit softwares same as the PC versions do? Or it is just the ARM version that would not be able to run the existing PC version softwares? If it is ARM now, would it be a 32 or 64 bit version in future?(Ofcourse if the mobile device architecture supports it). Will there be a separate version for Tablets, so that there would be no need for separate docking and allows seamless switching from Android to Ubuntu internally on the device?

Regards,
Premkumar. A

Comment: Overly broard question and impossible to answer unless, maybe, you work for Canonical and can not keep quiet.In short: we do not know and any answer would be guessing.

Comment: @Rinzwind thank you. I intend to ask this question to Canonical but I did not find a way to...

Answer (score 1):

**COMPLETELY REVISED**

---

***Ubuntu for Android*** -- use tag: **ubuntu-for-android**

[In every dual-core phone, there’s a PC trying to
get out.](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android)

*Ubuntu for Android* is designed to run on Dual-Core ARM-based smartphones. It is available from Canonical (Ubuntu 'owner') for OEMs to add to their smartphones (for sale). It is intended to provide the *Ubuntu desktop* experience, but based on the processing power, memory, and graphics capability of an advanced smartphone.

Currently, it has **not** yet addressed how to modify the interface, touch, memory usage, and other issues to better suit ARM-based mobile devices.

---

***Ubuntu on ARM*** -- use tag: **ubuntu-on-arm**

[wiki > Ubuntu Core on Nexus 7](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/)

Ubuntu for 'mobile' (tablets and smartphones, typically ARM-based) is currently under development and in early beta testing. Its current *reference platform* is the '*Google / ASUS Nexus 7*' 7-inch tablet.

This product (for Nexus 7) is specifically compiled to run on the ARM processor, work with the current ROM / BIOS of this device, and to allow testing (and improvements) to "Ubuntu core" for this type of platform.

---

Any question about the future, other platforms, and cross-architecture support are probably too early. Also, any answers would be subject to change, technology, market share, and other factors ..

*If you want a better answer, ask a single straight-forward question.*