# Remove Android OS from Toshiba Tablet AT105 and boot as Ubuntu

Tags: installation, android, tablet, ubuntu-for-android

Is it possible to completely remove Android OS from Toshiba Tablet AT105 and boot it as Ubuntu?

Comment: What has prompted the question? Have you got so far as rooting your device to run ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

***Simplest Answer:***

**No.**

The current development of *Ubuntu for Android* is focused on the *Nexus 7* reference platform.

See: [Need information regarding Ubuntu for Android](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220461/need-information-regarding-ubuntu-for-android)

---

There may be a solution tailored for the **Toshiba** AT105 tablet ..

Check out XDA Developers forums: [Welcome to xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

These solutions are typically Android-based, and allow some form of Linux / Ubuntu to be installed. They may also require 'rooting' your device, ROM-BIOS updates, and/or customization.